Should I use mixed effects model?
I have a sample of real sales data about plant-based products. These data are collected across a monthly period from 2019 to 2023. So I have some labels for this like "1-2019", "2-2019", "3-2019", and so on. But they are also changing across product categories (e.g., dairy products, meat products, salumi, etc.). Furthermore, they are collected across all the 110 Italian provinces.
I need to see the effects of assortment of plant-based products on their market share. I'm quite new to data analysis. Should I use a mixed-effects model? And if so, what would be my random effect and fixed effect?

Since you have evenly distanced time units, you could fit a model to be something like this in lme4, where you build a main and interaction effect between time and food category, along with the random effect of the provinces, like so:
fit1 <- lmer(sales ~ time * food + (1|provinces), data = data)

I will assume that if you have several time points, this relationship will change over time in a more nonlinear way for which a nonlinear fit with a default thin-plate spline may potentially be better, such as a GAM fit with mgcv. We add food as a linear effect (to get it's intercept/conditional mean) while allowing the change in sales with time by each food category in a nonlinear way. The s(provinces, bs = "re") part essentially does the same thing as the random intercept in the lmer model.
fit2 <- gam(sales ~ food + s(time, by = food) + s(provinces, bs = "re"), data = data)

Of course, if we are dealing with prices that fluctuate on a cyclic pattern, then cyclic smooths may in fact be better. It is also likely that the residuals would be autocorrelated given this is technically a time series, so adding an autocorrelation structure may be useful by using the gamm function in the gamm4 package, if required:
fit3 <- gamm(sales ~ food + s(time, by = food, bs = "cc") + s(provinces, bs = "re"), correlation = corARMA(form = ~ 1|Month, p = 1), data = data)


Fourier series are another option for including periodic terms in a generalized additive model.

(+1) for noticing that serial dependence may need to be accounted for!
